# rabbitmq login was refused in spring config server

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config-server

Unable to log in Rabbitmq while config-server is being configured.

this is in my config-service

`application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  application:
    name: config-service
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: {my_uri}
         
          
  rabbitmq:
    host: 127.0.0.1
    username: guest
    password: '{cipher}eebf968800a545119b8a02bfd8f6840280136886bdec98890346863fb6b20a84'
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: refresh, health, beans, bursefresh
```

`bootstrap.yml`

```
encrypt:
  key: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

but rabbitmq login was refuesd... why...?
If I change my password to plain text, it works fine.